# QR Code decoding using libdecodeqr

Tags: visual-studio, qr-code, decoding

I have successfully compiled and run libdecodeqr in visual studio 2005.But it failed to decode some qr codes created from same source(http://zxing.appspot.com/generator).After debugging I found that for failed qr codes, the 'mode' values are 15 and 9(in codedata.cpp).Is libdecodeqr is complete so that I can use it in my project ?. I need a qr code decoder based on opencv for one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at ZBar:

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks. But is it opencv based ?. I need one that is based on opencv

Comment: Dude - all you need to pass the library is an "image".  The fact that your application happens to use OpenCV is irrelevant to whichever QR library you invoke to do the QR reading.